# actionscript get location

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

How can I get the application itself full path in actionscript?

Comment: Actionscript or Flex app? server side or client installed application directory?

Comment: I build a flex app, the code is in actionscript for client desktop

Comment: It will get the C:\program files\ location.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using AIR, `stage.loaderInfo.url` will return app:/[SWF name].swf. Combine that with `File.applicationDirectory.nativePath` and voila.

Update: For in-browser app, Application.application.url or stage.loaderInfo.url should be enough (full url with params (not flashvars, url params if any - ...swf?param1=1.))

Comment: +1 I believe this would work for Flash Player apps as well. Not sure about the use of "stage" though, maybe in Flash.

Comment: No, it's AIR only, since it uses File class.

Comment: I was not referring to the File part, I was referring to the loaderInfo.url part.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Flex the root class [`Application`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Application.html) for Flash Player and [`WindowedApplication`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/WindowedApplication.html) for AIR.

Has a [url](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Application.html#url) property which returns:

> The URL from which this Application's SWF file was loaded.

Comment: In AIR that url will be app:/[SWF name].swf since it starts from app location.